# Inline list items changing position when li:active

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar that when one of the links are selected the link then becomes bold. However, when I click on one, the item to the right of it move position because the font gets larger thus making the width of the list item larger. Is there anyway to avoid this? I would like the text to stay in the same place. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS for the navigation bar. Is it an unordered list?

Comment: its an unordered list. its essentially like this. http://jsfiddle.net/JKFKC/10/

Comment: You could add styling to the `a` elements and give them a width plus a display of inline-block.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JKFKC/11/ that's basically what @j08691 suggested

Comment: well the problem is. I have three items. One is 162px long the other is 44px and the next is 50px. I dont want SO much space inbetween.

Comment: @Eric you can give each a specific width of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

Set a width on the `a` elements and make them inline-block.

```
​a {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You just have to make sure the width is wide enough allow the bolded text to show without breaking to two lines.

Second option: use a text shadow to make it *look* bold.

```
a.bolded {
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px black;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JKFKC/13/) showing both. I have the second one on hover but you can add or remove the class using jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two important events that you should target, when writing CSS for cases link this.
One is `:hover` and the other is `:active`.

They are called "Pseudo classes", and they give you the option to set the style of an element when you mouse-over it (:hover) and when you click on it (:active).

If you **set the style of the a tag the same as active and hover** (usually only hover is needed), then you should get the same results and the font size will stay the same.
Here's and example:

```
a, a:hover, a:active { font: normal 13px Arial; text-decoration: none; }
```

In a single CSS line, you could set all the styles to be the same.

*Important note*: you could use jquery, but there's no need for it (just saw you were using it on jsfiddle).